# Toggle Clickable LinearLayout

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have a problem. I created a clickable LinearLayout, with a custom xml selector. Now when I focus the LinearLayout the design changes like the way I want. But when I release the LinearLayout it goes back to normal. **I want to create some kind of toggle button, but with a LinearLayout**. Here is the **FULL** code of the LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0e2a56"
    android:weightSum="100">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" >
        <TextView
            android:text="Choose your shape:"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:background="@drawable/TriangleShapeButton"
            android:id="@+id/btnTriangle"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/triangle3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:background="@drawable/HexagonShapeButton"
            android:id="@+id/btnHexagon"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/hexagon2"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:scaleX="1.2"
                android:scaleY="1.2"  />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the custom XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="false">
    <layer-list>
      <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp" android:bottom="5dp" android:left="5dp">
        <shape>
          <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
          <solid android:color="#000000"/>
        </shape>
      </item>
      <item android:right="2dp" android:top="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp">
        <shape>
          <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#082e72" android:startColor="#104bb2"/>
          <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000"/>
          <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
          <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp"/>
        </shape>
      </item>
    </layer-list>
  </item>
  <item android:state_pressed="true">
    <layer-list>
      <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp">
        <shape>
          <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
          <solid android:color="#D6D6D6"/>
        </shape>
      </item>
      <item android:right="2dp" android:top="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp">
        <shape>
          <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#6b9fff" android:startColor="#4064a5"/>
          <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
          <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
          <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp"/>
        </shape>
      </item>
    </layer-list>
  </item>
</selector>
```

I thought that I could just use this code:

```
LinearLayout btnTriangle = view.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.btnTriangle);
btnTriangle.Click += (sender, e) => {
    btnTriangle.Pressed = true;
};
```

But that doesn't work!
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the `android:layout_width="0dp"` in `LinearLayout` ,So you cannot see your image.
I change the value from 0dp to 120dp

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_weight="50"
android:layout_height="120dp"
android:background="@drawable/TriangleShapeButton"
android:id="@+id/btnTriangle"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true">
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/triangle3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

I do not know your `<ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/triangle3"`, so I find another picture to replace it, there is running GIF.
[image]

**update：Do you need following result like following screenshot?**
[image]

There is code of layout(I changed `android:layout_width` from  `0dp` to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` mainly)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="#0e2a56"
 android:weightSum="100">

 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" >
    <TextView
        android:text="Choose your shape:"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="100"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/TriangleShapeButton"
        android:id="@+id/btnTriangle"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true">
         <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ring"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/TriangleShapeButton"
        android:id="@+id/btnHexagon"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true">
         <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ring"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Update: After setting  in `selector`** there is running GIF

[image]

CODE of selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected ="false" >
<layer-list>
  <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp" android:bottom="5dp" 
 android:left="5dp">
    <shape>
      <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
      <solid android:color="#000000"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:right="2dp" android:top="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" 
   android:left="2dp">
    <shape>
      <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#082e72" 
      android:startColor="#104bb2"/>
      <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000"/>
      <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
      <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" 
      android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
 </layer-list>
 </item>
 <item android:state_selected ="true">
 <layer-list>
  <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp">
    <shape>
      <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
      <solid android:color="#D6D6D6"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:right="2dp" android:top="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" 
   android:left="2dp">
    <shape>
      <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#6b9fff" 
       android:startColor="#4064a5"/>
      <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
      <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
      <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" 
    android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</layer-list>
</item>
</selector>
```

when I click the pic, change the state.

```
  LinearLayout btnTriangle = FindViewById<LinearLayout> 
 (Resource.Id.btnTriangle);

        btnTriangle.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            btnTriangle.Selected = !btnTriangle.Selected;

        };
```

Comment: I did that because I am using `weightSum` with android_weight="50" so the button is 50% of the screen

Comment: But how can I make the linearlayout toggle, so the state keeps pressed when I release the layout?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk Can you give me the all layout?

Comment: I added it to my question!

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk I edit my answer, Do you need the result like screenshot?

Comment: No, I have the same result. I want to create a LinearLayout that when I click on it, it holds the clickstate when I release. So when I click once and release, the white border stays. So a ToggleButton with a LinearLayout!

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk If you want to acheve keep state, you could set `<item android:state_selected ="true">` in selector